# Bengali Unicode String Length Difference

Tags: javascript, string, unicode

I have found following two different lengths of same string seen by eye.

```
"ব্রাহ্মণবাড়িয়া".length
16
"ব্রাহ্মণবাড়িয়া".length
14
```

What's the cause of this difference?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.length` in JS returns the number of codepoints in a string. Check it out yourself:

```
var a = "ব্রাহ্মণবাড়িয়া";
var b = "ব্রাহ্মণবাড়িয়া";

// this returns 16 elements:
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {console.log(a[i]);}
// 14 elements:
for (var i = 0; i < b.length; ++i) {console.log(b[i]);}
```

The difference is caused by characters being able to be represented in different ways: ড+় vs ড়, and য+় vs য়.